# Bootstrap 2.2.2 button dropdown toggle instantly closes on iOS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal

So as the title says I have a button dropdown toggle that instantly closes after opening. I've tried just about every fix I can find, with no luck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. You can see it here: NM

It's the search button, in the top right.

Comment: The very last version of Bootstrap 2 was Bootstrap 2.3.2, try using the jQuery that came with that version. Here's the issue on GitHub: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4550 -- it's a very long thread but people have individual fixes that you can try.

Comment: Scratch that.  Upgraded to 2.3.3, and problem solved.  Thanks Christina!